# How to back stack activities without recreating them

Tags: android-intent

I am new to android. I want to understand the activity stack.

I have 3 activities in my app `A(main)->B->C`. I want to navigate from `A->B->C` and back from `C->B->A` without restarting them, or changing their states (as the back button in the emulator does).

Also, when I press the home button, I want the app to go to thebackground and when I again launch the app by clicking the icon, the last activity should get resumed in the same state without restarting. I mean this: `A->B->C->(Home Button Pressed, App went to Background)->Launch` the App again by clicking the icon in `emulator->C`.

Plzz help me with this with codes coz I can't catch theory without demo :)

Comment: don't create or invent your own navigation patterns. Learn what Android offers and adapt to that. Life will be lot easier that way.

Comment: !!Wow!! I guess my question was technical not philosophical

Answer (score 0):

What you are describing is the default behavior in Android.

To handle Home button you don't have to code up anything. If you are in Activity C and you press Home button and later come back, you will still have Activity C the on top of the stack.

If you want to navigate A->B->C you just start your app with Activity A, later call `startActivity()` with Activity B, and later `startActivity()` with Activity C. If you are in Activity C and want to go back to B, just call `finish()` on Activity C.

Comment: Ya that I understood but I mean to say that after relaunching the app again activity A will start but I left the app in activity C so activity C should come up instead of A

Comment: Okay.. And what to define in the onResume() method for B and A to back stack without recreating them while moving from C->B->A